# Should I put the main in a class in Python?

Tags: python

So far I've running the `main()` module in a script way (different .py file and not in a class or whatever) and then call the different instances from my other modules.

Is this right or should I make a class just for the `main` too?

Regards and thank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Don't shoe-gaze over stuff that doesn't have a clear purpose. If you find a good reason to put a "main" function in a class, go ahead. Otherwise just save yourself the trouble.

To answer your question directly, I've never seen the "`main`" method defined in a `class` in python. The "main" function is usually just a driver for whatever you want to do with your program. It's something you want to execute every time your program is called. There's no general reason to represent this as an abstract data type, so I don't see the sense in encapsulating it in a class.

The python idiom I've seen most is to check `if __name__ == "__main__":`, which allows you to run a block of code only if the module is called directly, not as an `include` to another file. For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "This module was called directly."
```

You can see the question [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details.

Comment: Yes I know, but my question is if I should put:    class Whatever(): and then the main() and that at the end at the same level than the class or something

Comment: No you shouldn't. You can put your main function in the same file as a class, but there's no reason to nest it inside the class. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know whether you need a new class then you should not write it.